# Give access read/write to child object when owner changes old to new in salesforce?

Tags: apex-sharing

I have a `Case` Object, `P1` and `P2`. `P1` and `P2` has an lookup relationship with `Case`. The moment Case owner changes, original case creator should get the Read access on Case and P1 and P2 object.

In OWD, Case is `Private`, also `P1` and `P2` is `Private`. The moment, new Case owner becomes, he should be able to get Read/Edit access on the `P1` and `P2` object.

The code to give read permission

```
public static void giveReadPermission(Map<Id,SObject> newSobjsMap, Map<String,Id> mapRecTypeDevName, Map<Id,SObject> oldSobjsMap){
    Map<Id, Case> newCasesMap = (Map<Id, Case>)newSobjsMap;
    Map<Id, Case> oldCasesMap = (Map<Id, Case>)oldSobjsMap;

    List<CaseShare> shareList = new list<CaseShare>();  
    if(oldCasesMap != null){
        for(Id Ids : oldCasesMap.keyset()){
            Case oldcase = oldCasesMap.get(Ids);
            Case newCase = newCasesMap.get(Ids);

            CaseShare cShare = new CaseShare();
            cShare.caseId = Ids;
            cShare.UserOrGroupId = newCase.CreatedById;         
            cShare.CaseAccessLevel = 'Read';
            cShare.RowCause = 'Manual';
            shareList.add(cShare);
        }  
        insert shareList;
    }       
}
```

This will give read access to Child Object

```
public static void paymentInfo(Map<Id,SObject> newSobjsMap, Map<Id,SObject> oldSobjsMap, List<SObject> newSobjs){
    Map<Id, Payment__c> newPayMap = (Map<Id, Payment__c>)newSobjsMap;
    Map<Id, Payment__c> oldPayMap = (Map<Id, Payment__c>)oldSobjsMap;
    List<Payment__c> newpayList = (List<Payment__c>) newSobjs;

    Set<Id> caseIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    for(Payment__c pay : newpayList){
        caseIdSet.add(pay.Case__c);
    }

    List<Payment__Share> pay1ShareList = new List<Payment__Share>();

    if(oldPayMap != null){

        Map<Id,Case> caseMap = new Map<Id,Case>([SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIdSet]);

        for(Id Ids : oldPayMap.keyset()){
            Payment__c oldPay = oldPayMap.get(Ids);
            Payment__c newpay = newPayMap.get(Ids);

            Payment__Share payShare = new Payment__Share();
            payShare.ParentId = newpay.Id;
            payShare.AccessLevel = 'Read';
            payShare.RowCause = 'Owner';
            payShare.UserOrGroupId = newpay.OwnerId;
            pay1ShareList.add(payShare);
        }
        insert pay1ShareList;
    }
}
```

How we can make the owner of Case to Owner of Child object ? Which parameter do we need to consider ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update ownerId of the child records with the case ownerId

ChildObj.ownerId = CaseObj.ownerId;

Comment: +1 what I was typing, but terser.

Comment: Could you please show some code ?

Comment: @Kanika Added the code .

Answer (score 1):

Since the relationship is lookup and you want to explicitly change the owner , you will need to update the child records i.e Payement__c ownerId field in your trigger .

In the same code you will need to add these lines

```
for(Payment__c pay : newpayList){
    pay.ownerId = caseMap.get(pay.Case__c).ownerId;
    lstPaymentsToUpdate.add(newpay);
    caseIdSet.add(pay.Case__c);
}

update lstPaymentsToUpdate;//Outside loop
```

Comment: Do I need to create a separate method to have a access to the owner ? 3 different functionality should have a 3 separate method..right ?

Comment: Good to have in different methods if you are reusing it lot .

Comment: No, I mean shall I add this logic in paymentInfo() ? Not clear where to put the logic in above method ?

Comment: If I do FATAL_ERROR|System.FinalException: Record is read-only.. Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate and Trigger.isBefore && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)..